# What is the difference between IFoo foo = new Foo() and Foo foo = new Foo()

Tags: c#, .net, interface

```
public class Foo : IFoo
...
```

What is the difference between

```
IFoo foo = new Foo();
```

and

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Comment: Many dupes incl. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484445/why-are-variables-declared-with-their-interface-name-in-java

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595498/a-difference-in-style-idictionary-vs-dictionary

Comment: There are some subtleties in C# that aren't in Java involved though. See my comment on Jon's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is just in the declared type of the variable. That type will then be used by the compiler whenever you use the expression `foo`. For example, suppose the `Foo` class contains some method which *isn't* in `IFoo`. With the first declaration, that member won't be visible - you'd have to cast `foo` to type `Foo` to call it. In the second declaration, you'd have direct access to it.

The reverse is true for members of `IFoo` which are implemented with [*explicit interface implementation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) in `Foo`. This is *relatively* rare, but it does happen.

With the first declaration, you could also reassign the variable to a reference to any other object of a type implementing `IFoo`, e.g.

```
foo = new SomeOtherIFooImplementation();
```

whereas with the second declaration you can only assign values which are compatible with `Foo` - that is, instances of `Foo` or a derived class. (In both cases you could set the variable to be null, of course.)

Often it's advantageous to code to an interface rather than a particular implementation. It means the compiler will prevent you from using details which are specific to the implementation, which in turn means it's likely to be easier to change to a different implementation in the future.

The type of the variable also affects things like overload resolution:

```
DoSomething(foo);
```

may call different methods depending on whether `foo` is declared as `Foo` or `IFoo`.

Basically the compile-time type of a variable is important in all kinds of ways - virtually every time you use the variable, some aspect of the meaning of that code will depend on the type of the variable.

Comment: I would like to add that any members of IFoo that have been explicitly implemented in Foo are not visible with the second declaration, but are visible in the first.

Comment: Jon, you have almost exact linear increase on your reputation, expanding by around 15,700 each month. Considering the FAQ says you can only get a maximum of 200 rep a day, the most you should be able to get in a 30 day month is 6000 rep. Now how have you gone and got over twice that? You're showing us up here!

Comment: @Callum: It's not 15,700 per month - otherwise I'd have over 200K rep :) However, you can get over 200 rep in a day by having accepted answers. I think my average is about 280 per day.

Comment: Aha, that explains it. (I was only looking at 7 months, not a year, due to the reputation graph on your user page. My mistake)

Answer (score 1):

If foo is of type IFoo, and Foo implemented methods or properties that are not defined in IFoo, you wouldn't be able to access them unless you cast foo to Foo.

If foo is of type IFoo, you could instantiate other types that also inhert from IFoo and assign it to foo.  It's more abstracted, so you are not depending specifically on type Foo.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is an instance of some object implementing IFoo.
The second example is an instance of a Foo object.